# How to keep alert of Contact Form 7 below its floated input field

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have made this Wordpress form with Contact Form 7 plugin: http://ipermx.buensaltolabs.com/test-contact-form/

However, if you click SEND without filling the fields, the span .wpcf7-not-valid-tip shows floated and this causes the remaining fields shift down.

Can you help me keep the error messages below each field?

Thanks in advance
Javier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to `.wpcf7-form p`

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4kK0.png)

Comment: Grrreat! Thanks.